# Is it possible to express that a result may be null/may not be null depending on a Boolean parameter?

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

In C#, is it possible to express that a result may be null/may not be null depending on a Boolean parameter, something like the following (not compiling) code?

[Version 2 with Jeroen's suggestions in regards to `SingleOrDefault()` applied]

```
    [return: NotNullWhen(true, "noRowsThrows")]
    public DataRow? ExecuteToDataRow(SqlCommand command, bool noRowsThrows) {
        DataTable dataTable = ExecuteToDataTable(command);
        DataRow? result = dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().SingleOrDefault();
        if ((result is null) && noRowsThrows) throw new ArgumentException($"The command did not return any rows!");
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Are you asking for a statement that either returns bool or not depending on a bool value? For example if ```bool a = true``` the method returns null, if it is false the method returns some object.

Comment: Consider splitting this method in two. Nullability aside, using booleans to specify if exceptions should happen or not is not a very good pattern. The method is also basically duplicating the functionality of `.SingleOrDefault()` with a `null` check afterwards.

Comment: @Özgür: if parameter `noRowsThrows` is `true`, the result is never `null`, if parameter `noRowsThrows` is `false`, it might be.

Comment: I agree with Jeroen - split it into something like `DataRow? TryExecuteToDataRow(SqlCommand command)` and `DataRow ExecuteToDataRow(SqlCommand command)` and (if you want) make the original version `private` and call it with the appropriate parameters to implement the other methods.

Comment: @MatthewWatson On a method starting with "Try", I'd actually expect the `bool TryXXX( out T param)` pattern, am I wrong? Of course, this could be expressed by the `null`returned ... nevermind. I was just thinking loud.

Comment: @Fildor I suppose `ExecuteToDataRowOrNull` would be more in line with the `FirstOrNull` kind of methods.

Comment: @MatthewWatson absolutely agreed.

Comment: @Jeroen: Of course I can split it into two, but that is a bit ugly, filling up the intellisense suggestions. One method would be nicer than `ExecuteToDataRow` and `ExecuteToDataRowOrDefault`/`ExecuteToDataRowOrNull`. What do you not like on my pattern? Why do you think that is _not very good_?

Comment: I totally agree with @Fildor: `TryExecuteToDataRow` is out of the question as I would expect that all exceptions are swallowed and `null` returned if the execution of the query fails.

Comment: Because it leads to conundrums like the one posted in this question, where the method's return type is supposed to change based on a flag. :P A flag to distinguish between two *non-exceptional* cases is usually OK, but a flag that changes the method to throw in one case and not in another more often than not makes code harder to understand -- subjectively, of course. If you want *one* method, then just make it only `ExecuteToDataRowOrNull` and make the caller throw if the caller wants to/needs to -- `Execute... ?? throw new MoreDetailedExceptionMessageInContext()` likely leads to better code.

Comment: As an aside, unless you are dealing with code where the data you get is dynamic, `DataTable` and `DataRow` are inefficient, clunky millstones (memory use, especially for large tables, is pretty absurd). If your data is typed, an ORM like Dapper removes the boilerplate and also allows you to eliminate methods like these (because the caller can apply `.SingleOrDefault()`/`.Single()` directly on an `IEnumerable` result as necessary).

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Yes, upvote for Dapper (but don't dare to suggest EF). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I go for @Jeroen's first suggestion:

```
    public DataRow ExecuteToDataRow(SqlCommand command) {
        DataRow? result = ExecuteToDataRowOrNull(command);
        if (result is null) throw new ArgumentException($"The command did not return any rows!");
        return result;
    }

    public DataRow? ExecuteToDataRowOrNull(SqlCommand command) {
        DataTable dataTable = ExecuteToDataTable(command);
        return dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().SingleOrDefault();
    }
```

The later suggestion with `Execute... ?? throw new MoreAppropriateExceptionInContext()` is IMHO undesirable as then the caller has to care about the exception details which are going to be different with every call and then tend not to be as complete (the message of this example is of course also not very helpful but is in the sense of a minimal reproducible example, the production code would include the query text and map the `InvalidOperationException` back to an `ArgumentException`).

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
bool someBooleanVariable = true;

object? someObject = new Object(/*blah blah blah*/);

object? result = someBooleanVariable? (someObject ?? new Object()) : someObject;
```